# Grouping columns by unique values in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set with two columns and I need to change it from this format:

```
10  1 
10  5
10  3
11  5
11  4
12  6
12  2
```

to this

```
10  1  5  3
11  5  4
12  6  2
```

I need every unique value in the first column to be on its own row.

I am a beginner with Python and beyond reading in my text file, I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Comment: what is the field delimiter in your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pandas dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,10,10,11,11,12,12],'B':[1,5,3,5,4,6,2]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A  B
0  10  1
1  10  5
2  10  3
3  11  5
4  11  4
5  12  6
6  12  2
```

Let's use `groupby` and `join`:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.astype(str)))
```

Output:

```
A
10    1 5 3
11      5 4
12      6 2
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

an example using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) only; this is all in the python standard library (although the [`pandas` version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44606480/4954037) is way more concise!).

assuming the keys you want to group are adjacent this could all be done lazily (no need to have all your data in-memory at any time):

```
from io import StringIO
from itertools import groupby

text = '''10  1
10  5
10  3
11  5
11  4
12  6
12  2'''

# read and group data:
with StringIO(text) as file:
    keys = []
    res = {}

    data = (line.strip().split() for line in file)

    for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        keys.append(k)
        res[k] = [item[1] for item in g]

print(keys)  # ['10', '11', '12']
print(res)   # {'12': ['6', '2'], '10': ['1', '5', '3'], '11': ['5', '4']}

# write grouped data:
with StringIO() as out_file:
    for key in keys:
        out_file.write('{:3s}'.format(key))
        out_file.write(' '.join(['{:3s}'.format(item) for item in res[key]]))
        out_file.write('\n')
    print(out_file.getvalue())
    # 10 1   5   3
    # 11 5   4
    # 12 6   2
```

you can then replace the `with StringIO(text) as file:` with something like `with open('infile.txt', 'r') as file` for the program to read your actual file (and similar for the output file with `open('outfile.txt', 'w')`).

again: of course you could directly write to the output file every time a key is found; this way you would not need to have all the data in-memory at any time:

```
with StringIO(text) as file, StringIO() as out_file:

    data = (line.strip().split() for line in file)

    for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        out_file.write('{:3s}'.format(k))
        out_file.write(' '.join(['{:3s}'.format(item[1]) for item in g]))
        out_file.write('\n')

    print(out_file.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) subclass:

```
import collections
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in (l.split() for l in f.read().splitlines()):  # processing each line
        d[k].append(v)             # accumulating values for the same 1st column
    for k,v in sorted(d.items()):  # outputting grouped sequences
        print('%s  %s' % (k,'  '.join(v)))
```

The output:

```
10  1  5  3
11  5  4
12  6  2
```

Comment: matter of taste: i try to avoid `defaultdict` and replace it with `dict.setdefault` as in `d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)`. would you have an opinion on that?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, from python documentation: `This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using dict.setdefault():` https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#defaultdict-examples

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` may be easier. You can use `read_csv` function to read `txt` file where data is separated by space or spaces.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.txt", header=None, delimiter="\s+")
# setting column names
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2']
df
```

This is will give output of `dataframe` as:

```
    col1  col2
0    10     1
1    10     5
2    10     3
3    11     5
4    11     4
5    12     6
6    12     2
```

After reading `txt` file to `dataframe`, similar to `apply` in previous other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44606480/5916727), you can also use `aggregate` and `join`:

```
df_combine = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(lambda col: ' '.join(col.astype('str'))).reset_index()
df_combine
```

Output:

```
     col1     col2
0    10       1 5 3
1    11       5 4
2    12       6 2
```

Answer (score 0):

***I found this solution using dictonaries:***

```
with open("data.txt", encoding='utf-8') as data:
    file = data.readlines()

    dic = {}
    for line in file:
        list1 = line.split()
        try:
            dic[list1[0]] += list1[1] + ' '
        except KeyError:
            dic[list1[0]] = list1[1] + ' '
    
    for k,v in dic.items():
        print(k,v)
```

***OUTPUT***

> 10 1 5 3
>
> 11 5 4
>
> 12 6 2

***Something more functional***

```
def getdata(datafile):
    with open(datafile, encoding='utf-8') as data:
        file = data.readlines()

    dic = {}
    for line in file:
        list1 = line.split()
        try:
            dic[list1[0]] += list1[1] + ' '
        except KeyError:
            dic[list1[0]] = list1[1] + ' '

    for k,v in dic.items():
        v = v.split()
        print(k, ':',v)

getdata("data.txt")
```

***OUTPUT***

> 11 : ['5', '4']
>
> 12 : ['6', '2']
>
> 10 : ['1', '5', '3']