# Grouping by unique values while transposing column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I asked a similar question the other day with data from two columns:

[Grouping columns by unique values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606413/grouping-columns-by-unique-values-in-python/44611803)

Now I have three columns. They need to be grouped by column A with column B as the header values and column C sorted properly.

My data frame looks like:

```
    A   B   C
25115  20  45
25115  30  154
25115  40  87
25115  70  21
25115  90  74
26200  10  48
26200  20  414
26200  40  21
26200  50  288
26200  80  174
26200  90  54
```

But I need to end up with this:

```
       10   20   30   40   50   70   80   90
25115       45   154  87        21        74
26200  48   414       21   288       174  54
```

This gets the values of column C, but not with column B as the row names.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[25115,25115,25115,25115,25115,26200,26200,26200,26200,26200,26200],'B':[20,30,40,70,90,10,20,40,50,80,90],'C':[45,154,87,21,74,48,414,21,288,174,54]})
a = df.groupby('A')['C'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.astype(str)))
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: so couple of things, seems like all you did was copy the code that someone provided in the previous example for two columns without even modifying it, second, numerous people gave you good answers in that thread, and seems like you are using some of those answers yet you didn't accept any of their answers as being correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Option 1:

Use pivot_table:

```
df.pivot_table(values='C',index='A',columns='B')
```

Output

```
B        10     20     30    40     50    70     80    90
A                                                        
25115   NaN   45.0  154.0  87.0    NaN  21.0    NaN  74.0
26200  48.0  414.0    NaN  21.0  288.0   NaN  174.0  54.0
```

- Option 2:

Use set_index / unstack:

```
df.set_index(['A','B'])['C'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
B        10     20     30    40     50    70     80    90
A                                                        
25115   NaN   45.0  154.0  87.0    NaN  21.0    NaN  74.0
26200  48.0  414.0    NaN  21.0  288.0   NaN  174.0  54.0
```